# How to workout probability?

Tags: probability

I have a question if a coin is tossed 4 times what is the probability of getting two heads. Also less than 4 heads.

I don't know how to go about working this out.

Comment: Think about it this way : the probability of a head or tail is $\frac 12$. Now, out of four tosses, two must be heads. So we choose two out of four slots, and ensure these come heads, and the rest come as tails

Comment: Please add your attempted solution in the future.

Answer (score 2):

To get exactly two heads: $${4\choose{2}} \left(1\over{2}\right)^2 \left(1\over{2}\right)^2 = .375$$

Since we are choosing $2$ of the $4$ tosses to be heads with $p={1\over{2}}$

To get less than $4$ heads:

$${\sum_{k=0}^3} {4\choose{k}}\left(1\over{2}\right)^k\left(1\over{2}\right)^{4-k}=.9375$$

Since we are choosing $0,1,2, \text{or } 3$ of the $4$ tosses to be heads with $p={1\over{2}}$

This is the same as $$1 - P(\text{all heads}) = 1-\left(1\over{2}\right)^4=.9375$$

Answer (score 0):

**Scheme Solution**

Every toss you have $50$ % chance of getting either head or tail.

In $4$ tosses the scheme is the following

H H H H

H H H T

H H T H

H H T T

H T H H

H T H T

H T T H

H T T T

T H H H

T H H T

T H T H

T H T T

T T H H

T T H T

T T T H

T T T T

namely exactly $2^4$ combinations.

Now if you see how many of then have $2$ heads, then you see it's (since you said two heads and not AT LEAST, then it has to be EXACTLY TWO) $6$ out of $16$ hence

$$\frac{6}{16} = \frac{3}{8} = 0.375$$

Whilst LESS than $4$ means THREE but also TWO or ONE or ZERO, hence everyone except the four heads, hence

$$\frac{15}{16} = 0.9375$$

**Final Remark**

I decided to write the solution in a scheme way to make the OP to understand how to workout this in parallel with the solution provided above. I think both methods can be useful, this makes you to visualize the process, at least.

Comment: It's actually 6.

Comment: There are $6=\binom{4}{2}$ ways to get exactly two heads

Comment: @robjohn lol my (stupid) mistake!